# Writing specific value back to .csv, Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a .`csv` file with some data that i would like to change. 
It looks like this:

```
item_name,item_cost,item_priority,item_required,item_completed
item 1,11.21,2,r
item 2,411.21,3,r
item 3,40.0,1,r,c
```

My code runs most of what i need but i am unsure of how to write back on my `.csv` to produce this result

```
item_name,item_cost,item_priority,item_required,item_completed
item 1,11.21,2,x
item 2,411.21,3,r
item 3,40.0,1,r,c
```

**My code:**

```
print("Enter the item number:")
    line_count = 0
    marked_item = int(input())
    with open("items.csv", 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
        for line in reader:
            if line["item_required"] == 'r':
                line_count += 1
                if marked_item == line_count:
                    new_list = line
                    print(new_list)
                    for key, value in new_list.items():
                        if value == "r":
                            new_list['item_required'] = "x"
                            print(new_list)
    with open("items.csv", 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(new_list.values())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here

- you're using a `DictReader`, which is good to read data, but not as good to read and write data as the original file, since dictionaries do not ensure column order (unless you don't care, but most of the time people don't want columns to be swapped). I just read the title, find the index of the column title, and use this index in the rest of the code (no dicts = faster)
- when you write you append to the csv. You have to delete old contents, not append. And use `newline=''` or you get a lot of blank lines (python 3) or `"wb"` (python 2)
- when you read, you need to store all values, not only the one you want to change, or you won't be able to write back all the data (since you're replacing the original file)
- when you modify, you do overcomplex stuff I just replaced by a simple replace in list at the given index (after all you want to change `r` to `x` at a given row)

Here's the fixed code taking all aforementioned remarks into account

EDIT: added the feature you request after: add a `c` after `x` if not already there, extending the row if needed

```
import csv

line_count = 0
marked_item = int(input())
with open("items.csv", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    title = next(reader)  # title
    idx = title.index("item_required")  # index of the column we target

    lines=[]
    for line in reader:
        if line[idx] == 'r':
            line_count += 1
            if marked_item == line_count:
                line[idx] = 'x'
                # add 'c' after x (or replace if column exists)
                if len(line)>idx+1:  # check len
                   line[idx+1] = 'c'
                else:
                   line.append('c')
        lines.append(line)

with open("items.csv", 'w',newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(title)
    writer.writerows(lines)
```

Comment: thanks for that, it works perfectly! I'm now trying to add in one extra feature. I need to add in 'c' after the change is made to 'x'. It that possible to add in with the code you've provided? example output: item_1,21,1,x,c

Comment: i've given that a try but i get:  line[idx_r + 1] = 'c'
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("items.csv")

print("Enter the item number:")
marked_item = int(input())

df.set_value(marked_item - 1, 'item_required', 'x')

# This is the extra feature you required:
df.set_value(marked_item - 1, 'item_completed', 'c')

df.to_csv("items.csv", index = False)
```

Result when marked_item = 1:

```
item_name,item_cost,item_priority,item_required,item_completed
item 1,11.21,2,x,c
item 2,411.21,3,r,
item 3,40.0,1,r,c
```

Note that according to [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) you should keep the trailing commas.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should do the trick:

1. Open a file which can read and written to update it (use "+r" for that)
2. instead of opening it again write it right there using csvfilewriter, which we create at the start.

file.py

```
import csv
fieldnames = ["item_name","item_cost","item_priority","item_required","item_completed"]

csvfile = open("items.csv", 'r+')
csvfilewriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames,dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
csvfilewriter.writeheader()

print("Enter the item number:") 
line_count = 0
marked_item = int(input())
with open("items.csv", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        if line["item_required"] == 'r':
            line_count += 1
            if marked_item == line_count:
                new_list = line
                print(new_list)
                for key, value in new_list.items():
                    if value == "r":
                        new_list['item_required'] = "x"
                        print(new_list)
                        csvfilewriter.writerow(new_list)
```

If you don't want to update the csv but want to write a new one, below is the code:

```
import csv

fieldnames = ["item_name","item_cost","item_priority","item_required","item_completed"]

csvfile = open("items_new.csv", 'w')
csvfilewriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames,dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
csvfilewriter.writeheader()

print("Enter the item number:")
line_count = 0
marked_item = int(input())
with open("items.csv", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        if line["item_required"] == 'r':
            line_count += 1
            if marked_item == line_count:
                new_list = line
                print(new_list)
                for key, value in new_list.items():
                    if value == "r":
                        new_list['item_required'] = "x"
                        print(new_list)
                        csvfilewriter.writerow(new_list)

            else:
                csvfilewriter.writerow(line)
```

Comment: have you tested this code? you open the same file twice.

Comment: Yes i have, i intentionally did it, because I wanted to update it, you can use always choose to open a new file and do it as well

Comment: doesn't work on windows. Doesn't crash (surprising!) but file is not updated. With a new file it doesn't work as-is either.

Comment: try the new code, it will work The new code makes a new file called "items_new.csv". Let me know if this works on windows system

Comment: should work yes. But the code suffers from too much complexity: the header is already in the input file, so why hardcoding it? and this part is preposterous: `for key, value in new_list.items():
                    if value == "r":
                        new_list['item_required'] = "x"`. It should be `if new_list['item_required'] == "r": ...` no need to iterate through dictionary values!!. And last: the order of the new file are not in the same order as the original one due to the dictionary.

Comment: I understand that, I thought the solution should have similar logic as the original question that is the reason I did not change the logic